# Transform a natural number to a specific base and return it as a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to show the result of my function as a list not as a number.
My result is:

```
(define lst (list ))
(define (num->base n b)
  (if (zero? n)
     (append lst (list 0))
     (append lst (list (+ (* 10 (num->base (quotient n b) b)) (modulo n b))))))
```

The next error appears:

```
expected: number?
given: '(0)
argument position: 2nd
other arguments...:
10
```

Comment: In `(* 10 (num->base (quotient n b) b))` you're trying to multiply the list `(num->base (quotient n b) b)` by `10`. You're also creating a list of one element in both branches. It's difficult to say what to do about it as the purpose of the function is not clear.

Comment: BTW, since `lst` is the empty list, `(append lst (list 0))` is the same as `(list 0)`, and similarly for the other case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to rethink this problem. Appending results to a global variable is definitely not the way to go, let's try a different approach via tail recursion:

```
(define (num->base n b)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc '()))
    (if (< n b)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n b)
              (cons (modulo n b) acc)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(num->base 12345 10)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```